# Editing a file using FileWriter

Tags: java, android

I am trying to Edit a existing file which is in my R.raw folder 
i am able to read the file 
but when i run the write function it is not working .

```
    public void tofile(View v){ 
        BufferedWriter bw=null;
        FileWriter fw =null;
        try {
            String path = ("/Page2/res/raw/text.txt");
            File file = new File(path);
            fw = new  FileWriter(file);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write("hello");
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();   
          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
```

i even tried

fw = new  FileWriter(file,true);

if i add toast between even line it seems to get stuck at

fw = new FileWriter(fw);

Comment: *String path = ("/Page2/res/raw/text.txt");* , It is not a valid path on android.

Comment: Can you describe the specific error that you're getting better? Have you got logcat entries corresponding to these operations?

Comment: have you seen my post

Answer (score 0):

### You can't able to Write

As @CommonsWare said you can't write on resources but you could use internal storage using openFileOutput and openFileInput and BufferedReaders and BufferedWriters. You can check it here

### from the answer of @rodkarom in the following link

[Write to a Text File Resource in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457053/write-to-a-text-file-resource-in-android)

### and @Andro Selva says same thing in the following link

[How to write a file in Android to the raw folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628058/how-to-write-a-file-in-android-to-the-raw-folder)

you can able to read the content from the textfile which is present in the res/raw folder dude

read the file from res folder

```
public String readStringFromResource(Context ctx, int resourceID) {
        StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
        String sep = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        try {           
          InputStream is = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.trails);

          BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is), 1024*8);
          try {
            String line = null; 
            while (( line = input.readLine()) != null){
              contents.append(line);
              contents.append(sep);
            }
          }
          finally {
            input.close();
          }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find the file " + resourceID  + " " + ex);
            return null;
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            Log.e(TAG, "Error reading file " + resourceID + " " + ex);
            return null;
        }

        return contents.toString();
      }
```

check it and inform